# I don't understand that part of code about recursive (python)

Tags: python, recursion

I don't understand recursive part.

```
def length(list1):
    if list1 == [] or list1 == "":
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+length(list1[1:])




a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print "Length of list is: ",length(a)
```

This is code. and that code's role is like len function.
and `output is for a; 5`

but return `1+length(list1[1:])` that part is not understandable for me.
why there is `"1"`? and why it starts with 1? why not `"0"`?
I thought `length(list1[0:])` but it doesn't run.
actually i think but, ı understand nothing about that part.

can anyone explain?

Comment: I'd recommend you visualise this with something like http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit if you can't figure out what it does. This isn't a good question for SO.

Comment: `list1[0:]` is effectively just `list1` again, so that would loop forever.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, site is good. I didn't know that there is site like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of a list can be defined recursively as:

- 0 if the list is empty (equal to the empty list `[]`)
- 1 + the length of the list deprived of its first element. (e.g. if you have a list with 3 elements, the length is the same as 1 + the length of the same list without one of its element (2))

Here, `list1[1:]` is a new list similar to `list1` but without the first element.

If we take a concrete example with the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`:

`['a', 'b', 'c']` is different than the empty list `[]`, then we return `1 + length(['b', 'c'])`. `['b', 'c']` is different than the empty list `[]`, then `length(['b', 'c'])` returns `1 + length(['c'])`; and so on until `length([])` is called.

Comment: your edited information very good explanation. thank you so much. it is understandable

Answer (score 1):

In python: a[1:] means "take all values of a starting from 1, so excluding 0", for instance:

```
"abc"[1:] == "bc"
[2, 3, 4][1:] == [3, 4]
```

The function you are looking at takes either a list or a string, then remove an item and counts the remaining until it find an empty one, in this case returns its length (0).

Comment: I know that part why 1.
actually why there is "1" out of that code? "1+length(blabla"